# display setFlash on specific div

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I want to display setFlash message on specific div.
here is my controller and view page code.

my controller code is:

```
public function actionCreate() {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'message');
        return $this->redirect(['site/page']);
}
```

my view page code is:

```
<section class="main">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading panel_heading">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            (get flash message here)
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your php page you must insert the proper echo

```
use common\widgets\Alert;

<section class="main">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading panel_heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
         <?= Alert::widget() // get flash message here) ?> 
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: tanks a loat. It was useful

Comment: could you please vote may question? I'm question ban :-(

Comment: I really appreciate you. :-)